# apache redirects with different destination depending on whether one of several files exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a static website (served by Apache) where one can download software packages. These packages first appear in the "devel" section of the site and then at some point they become available in the "release" section as well. The packages can live in one of several "repositories", but each package is guaranteed to have a unique name across all repositories. Let's say that my repository names are repos1, repos2, and repos3.

So currently I have URLs like this:

```
/packages/release/repos1/html/mypkg.html
/packages/devel/repos1/html/mypkg.html
```

I want to set up redirects such that a user can go to:

```
/packages/mypkg/
```

...and the rewrite rule will try all the following URLs and redirect to the first one that exists (or to the 404 page if none do). So for the request `/packages/mypkg/`:

```
/packages/release/repos1/html/mypkg.html
/packages/release/repos2/html/mypkg.html
/packages/release/repos3/html/mypkg.html
/packages/devel/repos1/html/mypkg.html
/packages/devel/repos2/html/mypkg.html
/packages/devel/repos3/html/mypkg.html
```

It's not clear to me how to do this with mod_rewrite. I know there is the special RewriteCond pattern `-f`, but it seems before I can use it I have to process the `REQUEST_FILENAME` in such a way that I can parse out the package name with a backreference.

Just to make things more complicated, if the user knows whether they are looking for a release or devel package I want to honor that, so `/packages/devel/mypkg/` should redirect to `/packages/devel/X/html/mypkg.html` where `X` is the first repository where Apache finds the file. Any ideas?

Comment: How many `reposX` do you have ? Can it grow in a dynamic way ? It can be done with *mod_rewrite* but in a static way (like a condition by repository)

Comment: There are only 3 repositories and no plans to change that number. I'm curious how this could be done in a static way as you suggest. BTW, I also realized that I could automatically generate an .htaccess file when the site is generated (I use a static site-generation tool) which specifies every possible redirect. That seems to be working but I'm curious about a more elegant approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no elegant way of doing this with *mod_rewrite*.

Anyway, you can put this code in your `/packages/.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /packages/

################################################################################
# /packages/release/xxx or /packages/devel/xxx are internally rewritten to
# /packages/release/reposX/html/xxx.html or /packages/devel/reposX/html/xxx.html
# Note: (reposX) X is the first repos where xxx is found
################################################################################
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/$1/repos1/html/$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(release|devel)/([^/]+)/$ $1/repos1/html/$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/$1/repos2/html/$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(release|devel)/([^/]+)/$ $1/repos2/html/$2.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/$1/repos3/html/$2\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(release|devel)/([^/]+)/$ $1/repos3/html/$2.html [L]

################################################################################
# /packages/xxx is internally rewritten to
# /packages/release/reposX/html/xxx.html or /packages/devel/reposX/html/xxx.html
# Note: all release repos are fetch first, then devel ones
#      (reposX) X is the first repos where xxx is found
################################################################################
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/release/repos1/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ release/repos1/html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/release/repos2/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ release/repos2/html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/release/repos3/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ release/repos3/html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/devel/repos1/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ devel/repos1/html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/devel/repos2/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ devel/repos2/html/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/packages/devel/repos3/html/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ devel/repos3/html/$1.html [L]
```